# Can you play coop online?

Tags: nba2k12

I've been googling quite a bit and can't find anything definitive. Does NBA 2K12 allow co-op play online?  My friend and I want to play on the same team but not have to be in the same house together.

If it does, which modes support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NBA 2K12 supports 2-10 player network games.